# AngularJS directives - Isolated Scope and Inherited Scope

Tags: angularjs

I've been trying to understand the difference between isolated scope and inherited scope in directive. This is an example I prepared to make myself understand:

**The HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="AppController">
    <div my-directive>
        Inside isolated scope directive: {{myProperty}}
    </div>

    <div my-inherit-scope-directive>
        Inside inherited scope directive: {{myProperty}}
    </div>
</div>
```

**The JS**

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
        .directive("myInheritScopeDirective", function() {
            return {
                restrict: "A",
                scope: true
            };
        })
        .directive("myDirective", function() {
            return {
                restrict: "A",
                scope: {}
            };
        })
        .controller("AppController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
            $scope.myProperty = "Understanding inherited and isolated scope";
        }]);
```

Executing the code with Angular-1.1.5, it works as I expected: The {{myProperty}} inside my-directive will be `undefined` because of isolated scope, whereas for my-inherit-scope-directive, {{myProperty}} will have the value `Understanding inherited and isolated scope`.

But executing with Angular-1.2.1, in both the directives {{myProperty}} outputs `Understanding inherited and isolated scope`.

Anything I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text node inside your directive is bound to the controller scope. Therefore the scope of the directive has no effect. I think this has [changed](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/d0efd5eefcc0aaf167c766513e152b74dd31bafe) as of v1.2. You have to use a template for your directive:

```
.directive("myIsolatedDirective", function () {
    return {
        template: 'Inside isolated in template scope directive: {{myProperty}}',
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            myProperty: '='
        }
    };
})
```

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LB9U6/1/).

Comment: Thanks @Reto, then whats the point of isolated scope in v1.2, if it inherits property from the controller.

Comment: It is about the template inside the directive. If you remove the scope isolation from the `myIsolatedDirective` the `myProperty` will be bound to the controller scope. I think the behavior in 1.1.x was not intended as Vojta stated: “Child elements that are defined either in the application template or in some other directives template do not get the isolate scope. In theory, nobody should rely on this behavior, as it is very rare - in most cases the isolate directive has a template.”

Comment: Thanks @Reto or the explanation.