# why can I access the property defined outside the isolated scope?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following HTML:

```
<ng-view>
    <tabset>
        <tab>
            <tab-heading>
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i>
            </tab-heading>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>{{selectedWord.translation}}</div>
                </div>
    ...
</ng-view>
```

And the controller which is loaded for the view:

```
angular.module('app').controller('SampleController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.selectedWord = {translation: '[te]'};
}
```

The directive `ng-view` creates a new scope which I presume then is injected into the `SampleController` constructor as a parameter.

`tabset` creates its own isolated scope so it doesn't inherit properties from the scope created by the `ng-view`.

```
.directive('tabset', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      type: '@'
    },
```

Each `tab` directive also creates its own scope which also is not inherited from the scope created by the `tabset` directive.

```
.directive('tab', ['$parse', function($parse) {
  return {
    require: '^tabset',
    restrict: 'EA',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'template/tabs/tab.html',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      active: '=?',
      heading: '@',
      onSelect: '&select', //This callback is called in contentHeadingTransclude
                          //once it inserts the tab's content into the dom
      onDeselect: '&deselect'
    },
```

What I don't understand is why it is possible to access the property `selectedWord.translation` defined in the scope created by the `ng-view` directive from inside the scope created by the `tab` directive (which is isolated scope itself and is preceded by the isolated scope created by the `tabset`) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a directive uses transclusion, it creates a child scope for the transcluded contents (sometimes also referred to as transclusion scope). When a directive also defines an isolated scope, there are actually two scopes being used in the same directive:

> 1. Transclusion Scope - bound to the transcluded contents
> 2. Isolated Scope - bound to your template (if defined) or available as a private scope for your directive.

So the reason that `selectedWord` is resolvable is because the transcluded contents are bound to the transclusion scope of ngView. And the transclusion scope of any directive is just a child scope that prototypically inherits scope from its parents.

This is true of any directive that uses transclusion:

**Example**

```
<!-- name defined in parent scope -->
<div ng-init="name='test'">
    <!-- ng-if creates a child scope for its transcluded contents
       The child scope prototypically inherits scope from its parents -->
    <div ng-if="true">
        <!-- this is the transcluded contents for ng-if -->
        <div> 
            <my-dir-using-isolate-scope>
               <!-- this is the transcluded contents for 
                    my-dir-using-isolate-scope directive --> 
               {{ name }} 
            </my-dir-using-isolate-scope>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know any good resource besides the `docs.angularjs.org` where there is a good explanation about transcluded scopes?

Comment: Where is or how is `transcluded contents` defined?

Comment: Whenever you have contents inside of a element that has a directive - *that is* the tanscluded contents. There's nothing special about transclusion scope. Its just a child scope. A directive with a template will overwrite the transcluded contents with its template. But then you can also link the transcluded contents into your template by applying the ng-transclude directive inside your template.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the elaborate answer! I've also found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20656168/angularjs-directives-isolated-scope-and-inherited-scope?rq=1) question and answer - does it have anything to do with transcluded contents? I'd assume that `Inside isolated scope directive: {{myProperty}}` is a transcluded contents inside `my-inherit-scope-directive` directive and so it gets access to `myProperty` through a transcluded scope?

Comment: Ah, I'm smart :)))... thanks! :) The guy didn't explicitly stated that  directive is `transcluded`, so I guess it is set to `true` by default?

Comment: Hey, can you please check my [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24726335/how-can-i-select-a-tab-from-outside-controller) post? Thanks!

Comment: There is no transclusion happening in that post. Transclusion only applies when you have a template. But it still true that the contents under the directive are compiled and linked against the outer scope (outside of the directive).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I know there is no transclusion there. I just can't figure out how I can switch tabs from outer controller?

Comment: Maybe post another question?

Comment: Yeah, I did. It's [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24726335/how-can-i-select-a-tab-from-outside-controller). Or do you mean another one besides this one?

Comment: It seems you have more questions in addition to this one. Its more likely you'll get an answer by posting another question rather than asking it in a comment. I'm sure these additional comments will confuse the answer to this one.