# ng-repeat uses parent scope which is separated by two preceding isolated parent scopes - why

Tags: angularjs

I have this simple HTML:

```
  <div ng-controller="MainController">
    <tabset>
      <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" disabled="tab.disabled">
```

`MainController` creates its own scope, `tabset` directive creates its own isolated scope, `tab` directive also creates its own isolated scope, and `ng-repeat` creates its own child scope as well. So we have like 4 scopes here. I'm told that `ng-repeat` will use `MainController`'s scope to find `tabs` property. My question is why if there are two scopes created by `tabset` and `tab` in between? Is it because those scopes are isolated?

**EDIT:**
I'm adding the picture of my understanding based on the answers in comments

[image]

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: ng-repeat will loop over the tabs defined on MainContollers scope. If you look at the source code for the ng-repeat directive, it creates a child scope that inherits from MainController's scope. So each iteration of ng-repeat creates it's own child scope and binds the model 'tab' from the expression "tab in tabs" to this scope. ng-repeat has to create a separate child scope for each iteration so that they are separate from eachother.

Comment: The tab directive is applied against each child scope created by ng-repeat, and the tab model is used to bind 'tab.active' to the tab directive's isolated scope.

Comment: @pixelbits, `it creates a child scope that inherits from MainController's scope.` - why doesn't it inherit from `tabset`'s scope? Is it because `tabset`'s  is isolated? I don't understand because logically it should inherit since `tab` DOM element is a child of `tabset` DOM element.

Comment: You are right. the tabset directive defines a template and uses transclusion. So it will automatically create a child scope bound to tabsets transcluded contents. This transclusion scope inherits from MainControllers scope. ng-repeat will create child scopes that are children of tabset's transclusion scope.

Comment: Now it's going to make sense to me... so the transcluded scope is in play here. So `tab` element doesn't inherit from `tabset`'s isolated scope because `tabset` directive uses transclusion which makes `tab` a transcluded content with transcluded scope inherited from the `MainController` , correct? Let me now draw a general case.

Comment: Child scopes form the prototypical inheritance chain on the main page (this includes transclusion scopes). Isolated scopes are for directives and their templates only. Tab does not inherit from tabsets isolate scope because tab is not defined in tabsets template.

Comment: That is a good general picture.  The child scopes create an inheritance chain. Isolated scopes are outside of that chain. The transclusion (child) scope and the isolated scope are sister scopes. The translusion scope is bound to your transcluded contents.  The isolated scope is bound to your directive's template.

Comment: Thanks, I guess we have sorted out this question. Thanks a lot for your help and patience! Do you think you could post an answer to this question so that I accept it?